# Is paging broken with spring data solr when using group fields?

Tags: spring, solr, pagination, group-by, spring-data-solr

I currently use the spring data solr library and implement its repository interfaces, I'm trying to add functionality to one of my custom queries that uses a Solr template with a SimpleQuery. it currently uses paging which appears to be working well, however, I want to use a Group field so sibling products are only counted once, at their first occurrence. I have set the group field on the query and it works well, however, it still seems to be using the un-grouped number of documents when constructing the page attributes.

is there a known work around for this?

the query syntax provides the following parameter for this purpose, but it would seem that Spring Data Solr isn’t taking advantage of it. `&group.ngroups=true` should return the number of groups in the result and thus give a correct page numbering.

any other info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two ways to add this parameter.

Queries are converted to the solr format using `QueryParser`s, so it would be possible to register a modified one.

```
QueryParser modifiedParser = new DefaultQueryParser() {

    @Override
    protected void appendGroupByFields(SolrQuery solrQuery, List<Field> fields) {

        super.appendGroupByFields(solrQuery, fields);
        solrQuery.set(GroupParams.GROUP_TOTAL_COUNT, true);
    }
};

solrTemplate.registerQueryParser(Query.class, modifiedParser);
```

Using a `SolrCallback` would be a less intrusive option:

```
final Query query = //...whatever query you have.

List<DomainType> result = solrTemplate.execute(new SolrCallback<List<DomainType>>() {

    @Override
    public List<DomainType> doInSolr(SolrServer solrServer) throws SolrServerException, IOException {

        SolrQuery solrQuery = new QueryParsers().getForClass(query.getClass()).constructSolrQuery(query);

        //add missing params
        solrQuery.set(GroupParams.GROUP_TOTAL_COUNT, true);

        return solrTemplate.convertQueryResponseToBeans(solrServer.query(solrQuery), DomainType.class);
    }
});
```

Please feel free to [open an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR).

Comment: Iv looked closer and it seems that in the DefaultQueryParser is the following line `solrQuery.setParam(GroupParams.GROUP_MAIN, true);` that causes the results of the group query to be flattened and returned as normal results in the response, which is great except that the group count value is returned as an attribute of the groups. so in the examples you described it will not be returned at all. I have modified the SolrTemplate to handle group queries without the `GroupParams.GROUP_MAIN' but Im not sure it is the correct solution. It does not break any of the libraries tests or my own tests.